# How to vertically align <span> in different <li>

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new to these languages and I have a simple question, but I can't figure out how to solve it. In my jQuery file I use two spans (the name of who has written a comment and the comment itself); these two spans are in the same `<li>`, so I have an unordered list of names and the related comments. I would like to vertically align the comments (because a name could be longer than another name). Can someone help me?

(I have copied the jQuery code necessary for this question, so some variables may not have been initialized here, but the code itself is correct).

EDIT
I've also uploaded my css, but now it inserts the second name immediately after the first comment (on the same line).

```css
#reviews > ul > li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.rev_name{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.rev_comment{
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```js
var ris = JSON.parse(json);
$("#reviews").html("<ul></ul>");
for(var i=0; i<ris.length; i++){
  var name = "<span class='rev_name'>"+ ris[i].username + "</span>";
  var comment = "<span class='rev_comment'>"+ ris[i].commento + "</span>";
  $("#reviews > ul").html($("#reviews > ul").html()+"<li>" + name + " " + comment + "</li>");
}

//#reviews is a div in which I insert the list of comments
```

Comment: use 'display:block' in span tag

Comment: With 'display:block' the comments go on a lower line, but I would like the name and the related comment on the same line

Comment: Then give specific width in percentage to both span tag along with float:left.

Comment: The sum of width of both the elements should be 100%.. or else you can wrap both the element inside another div or another element with display:block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a **display:flex** !

```
#reviews > ul > li{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display:flex;
}

.rev_name{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 19px;
  width: 20%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.rev_comment{
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add classes to your spans and manipulate your css from there easily.

```
.name {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.comment {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
#reviews > ul > li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo097/j90huLez/29/